# PHP force download, Not working with variables

Tags: php, image, header, force-download

When

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=1330554893-COVER.jpg');
header('Content-type: jpeg');
readfile('watermarked/1330554893-COVER.jpg');
```

Is run in a file for example "testdownload.php" It downloads the image

> "watermarked/1330554893-COVER.jpg"

and names it

> "1330554893-COVER.jpg"

But when I try make the code dynamic to download different files.

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$newFileName}");
header("Content-type: jpeg");
readfile("{$findFile}");
```

where 
$newFileName = "1330554893-COVER.jpg" and $findFile = "watermarked/1330554893-COVER.jpg"

It downloads an image "1330554893-COVER.jpg" but it cannot be opened and I get an error "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because eaither Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format"

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: try echo file_get_contents($findfile); first. maybe there is a path or permission problem.

Comment: please try `readfile($findFile)`

Comment: @silly readfile($findFile) Creates the same error

Comment: @Eduard7 I did the echo and it created random symbols which is what I believe to be image. Yep. When I do `echo file_get_contents($findFile);` `header("Content-type: jpeg");` it shows the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allrite then, don't use readfile(), try echo file_get_contents after the headers!